# SQLBindParameter is working fine but SQLExecute gives error in Windows 2008 Server 64bit

Tags: windows

I am migrating my application from 32bit(Windows 2003 Server) to 64bit (Windows 2008 Server R2).I am getting the following while trying to execute a SQL command

Encountered ODBC error -1: S1010, 0, [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error .

Basically internal function call is SQLExecute() function call. This works perfectly for Windows 2003 Server 32bit. I tried the command execute at the background from the command prompt and it is working.

Any help or suggestion would be very much appreciated.

I checked the squence of call.We have two consecutive SQLBindParameter function call and then we call SQLExecute. Is this sequence incorrect in case of 64bit? I also checked the return code given by SQLExecute which is 99.

Any pointers or suggestions would be very helpful. The above sequence is working fine with 32bit Windows.

Thanks in advance.

-R

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit ODBC driver?

Comment: I am newbie to DB development.Please let me know how do I check that ?
Thanks,
-R

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but on Oracle database.  The way I fixed it was granting 'execute' privileges on my procedures and 'select, insert, update, delete' privileges on my views and tables.  Hope this helps.